# Recursion and lists in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
class a():
    Requirement = 0
    def func(self, oldlist, x):
        newlist = [None]*3
        newlist = oldlist
        newlist[x]  = b()
        print "Class a"
        g(newlist)


class b():
    Requirement = 1


def g(list):
    for i in range(3):
        if list[i].Requirement==0:
            list[i].func(list,i)

Initiallist=[None]*3
Initiallist[0]=a()
Initiallist[1]=b()
Initiallist[2]=a()
g(Initiallist)
```

Instead of trying to express what I expect in words, I made some diagrams that express what in my mind should happen:

[image]

Which would imply that the function inside class a should be called 4 times. However, it only gets called 2 times, so it seems that this is happening:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening or how I should fix it.

Comment: Please correct your indentation of the code in the question.

Comment: You'll want to correct your formatting, since this is critical in Python for your program to run as intended. It lets people run it more easily and try it out on their systems.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I just fixed it. Thank you for adding the pictures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but I think your problem is this line:

```
newlist = oldlist
```

I guess you want to copy the list (and not altering `oldlist`), so you should simply use:

```
newlist = oldlist[:]
```

---

So changing `func` to

```
def func(self, oldlist, x):
    newlist = oldlist[:]
    newlist[x] = b()
    print "".join(x.__class__.__name__ for x in newlist)
    g(newlist)
```

prints

> bba
>   bbb
>   abb
>   bbb

Comment: remember to tick this as answer if you like it =)

Answer (score 0):

In `func` you need to create a copy of `oldlist`, otherwise it will modify the same list.